# How to make every service wait for the services it needs to be ready?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, promise

I am struggling getting the coding of waiting for dependent services to prepare their data. I have a brain lock at the moment and I am not getting the behavior I expect.
My expectation is that the home.ts page depends on the B service which in turn depends on the A service completing first. Additionally, I do not want to make home.ts page aware of A service (ideally).

I have made the following simplified attempts in stackblitz the 1st uses a Ready_P promise exposed by each service. However, I now realize that often depending on the injection mechanism it is undefined and thus the line this.BService.Ready_P.then().. fails in the constructor of home.ts.

What's a better/correct way of handling this?

```
// home.ts
import { CService } from './CService'; // 20220122
import { BService } from './BService'; // 20220122

//
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.scss'],
  // encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class home {
  constructor(
    //
    //
    public CService: CService,
    public BService: BService
  ) {
    this.Init();
  }
  //
  async Init() {
    await this.CService.Load();
    console.log('CService Ready from home');

    await this.BService.Load();
    console.log('BService Ready from home');
  }
}

// C.ts
import { BService } from './BService'; // 20220122

/** # CService Depends on BService being data ready
 *  - 20220122 */
@Injectable()
export class CService {
  // 20220122
  constructor(
    //
    public BService: BService
  ) {
    // this.BService.Load().then(() => {
    //   console.log('BService Ready from C');
    //   this.Load();
    // });
  }
  //
  //
  Ready_P: Promise<boolean>;
  //
  async Load() {
    await this.BService.Load()
    // Do work
    // if (this.Ready_P) return this.Ready_P; // to avoid repeated execution.
    return (this.Ready_P = new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('C Resolves');
        resolve(true);
      }, 1000);
    }));
  }
}

// B.ts

import { AService } from './AService'; // 20220122

/** # BService Depends on AService being data ready
 *  - 20220122 */
@Injectable()
export class BService {
  // 20220122
  constructor(
    //
    public AService: AService
  ) {
  }
  //
  //
  Ready_P: Promise<boolean>;
  //
  async Load() {
    await this.AService.Load()
    // Do work
    // if (this.Ready_P) return this.Ready_P // to avoid repeated execution.
    return (this.Ready_P = new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('B Resolves');
        resolve(true);
      }, 2000);
    }));
  }
}

// A.ts is similar to C
```

The complete code can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-atyngp?file=pages%2Fhome%2FCService.ts).

NOTE: I would like my A, B, C services to be coded ideally using the same pattern.  The services may or may not use http.get... or the like to complete and prepare some data.  For simplicity I have used the setTimeout() to model that they will take some varying time to complete.

the expected sequence of execution

```
1. A Resolves

2. AService Ready from B

3. B Resolves

4. BService Ready from C

5. C Resolves

6. CService Ready from home

7. BService Ready from home
```

Comment: Promises and `await` or `.then()`.

Comment: Given that I have been at this TS/JS hacking for sometime, I am 100% sure that I will never fully grasp the correct use and essence of things like Promises, Observable, Async/Await, rxjs, ... however, I have a general understanding and really code by cut/paste approach that seems to have worked for me in the past.
Would you be kind enough to articulate what you meant by your response above await or .then, I don't think I have mixed them in my plunkers.  Thank you.

Comment: Well, so far all the code you show in your question is just scaffolding - it doesn't really do anything.  It's about 100-1000x harder to teach an entire generic topic (like promises) than it is solve a specific real world coding problem and then let you learn from that solution.  If you show  a real world coding problem with real code, not pseudo-code or just code scaffolding, then I'd be happy to see about offering a solution.  But, I can't really try to teach the general concept of promises and `async/await` and `.then()` in the scope of one answer to one question.

Comment: And coding by cut/paste without understanding the underlying concepts will not lead to good, solid, reliable code.  It's worth spending time learning the underlying concepts.  That will pay off for you.

Comment: And, don't use `http.get()` for making http requests to other servers.  It's too low a level, does not support promises and requires a lot of extra coding to make it work well.  Instead, get a library like `got()` or `axios()` for easier programming with promises.

Comment: I treat certain topics this way: don't *try* to learn anything, code until I get into trouble, learn something accidentally, repeat. (I do this with CSS, except I never learn *anything*). But for promises, though, you'll find it worthwhile to pause, create a toy project and learn the basics.  Suggestion: project A, banish "async/await", and learn when to create a promise, when NOT to, how to create, and learn .all(), .then(), .catch() and .finally().  In project B, rewrite project A with try/catch and async/await.

Comment: On this specific issue, take the async work out of the constructors which cannot return promises. Give each class an async load method that awaits the load() of its upstream dependency.

Comment: @danh that's exactly what I tried to do is create some simplified examples and believe me they are off a real project but details are irrelevant to the question. What seemed to be working for the last 2 years is breaking saying undefined. That's what made me revisit "my pattern" trying to refresh my understand of promises (loading stuff from local storage, remote json/API, build massage data for my views, ...),  I am using HttpClient I did not mean to tick off anyone :)  setTimeout models the async charactestics that enough.

Comment: @danh  I too share the same frustration with CSS, at times, I think because they keep adding more junk instead of overhauling the whole language.  The following example seems to be doing what I want it.  Do you see any problem with it? 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wspjhu?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts
I have not yet attempted to make a fork and change the Load() methods to async.  I can understand this code, in a couple of weeks, in a month or two I am not sure :)

Comment: @danh I attempted to code what you suggested by making each service Load() an async method that awaits its dependent services Load() to complete. However, I am seeing in the console the Load of each service is executing multiple times.
Check it out...
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-atyngp?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

Comment: I'm going to edit your question to contain the code in the most recent stackblitz link. It's on a good track.  I answered about it in further detail below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. The reason you're seeing duplicates is that home calls init for B and C, and B inits A, and C inits B, so you end up with

```
home -> B -> A
home -> C -> B -> A
```

Notice that A and B will get initialized twice. If the classes really have this dependency, then add a side-effect to the init process the class knows it's done. Something like:

```
asnyc Load() {
  if (this.wasLoaded) return Promise.resolve();
  await this.otherService.Load();
  this.wasLoaded = true;
}
```

One "side-effect" of the load might be that some instance data on the object is getting set. The presence of that data might be a good flag for whether Load needs to execute.

The other thing to fix is that you've successfully removed the async calls from the constructors of service A, B, C, but your `home` class calls its (async) `Load()` method from the constructor. Remove that, too.

Stylistically, the most modern syntax is presented in your `home` class. It's a style thing, but I'd copy that syntax (mark methods that use `await` as being `async` and use `await` instead of `then()`), to your other classes.

Lastly, in the `async/await` style, errors are caught with `try/catch` blocks, as in...

```
// in class A
async Load() {
  if (this.dataWeGetFromB) return Promise.resolve();
  try {
    this.dataWeGetFromB =  await this.BService.Load();
  } catch (err) {
    // handle err
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @danh for taking the time, I think I had already started calling Init() in home.ts to get around, I assume, the fact that a constructor cannot be decorated with async?
in the example I shared above https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-atyngp?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts perhaps you were looking at a different plunker.

Comment: I have introduced the boolean flag whichI am already using in my production code/project to handle the fact that a service has already acquired some data and prepared it for access thru props.  I usually cache that data/books and what not, and expose what I want via the service props.  
Here is my edits minus the try catch. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-knvkms?file=pages%2Fhome%2FCService.ts

Comment: I get the expected sequence of execution
A Resolves,

AService Ready from B,

B Resolves,

BService Ready from C,

C Resolves,

CService Ready from home,

BService Ready from home,

Comment: So, all good?  The constructor can’t return a promise because it returns the new instance. Awaiting within it is effectively returning a promise.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't recommend using Promises for this purpose. Instead, Angular has a much better way to handle asynchronous code that depends on other code to finish.

Using your code, I'd write it this way:

Service A:

```
@Injectable()
export class AService {
  // this service demonstrates dependance on http - an action that takes time to finish
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public load() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
  }
}
```

*Note*: For the purpose of the demo, I made this service depend on http - an action that takes time to finish.

Service B:

```
@Injectable()
export class BService {
  private dataStoreExample: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private AService: AService) {}

  get dataFromServiceB() {
    return this.dataStoreExample.asObservable();
  }

  public load() {
    this.AService.load().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('A Resolves');
      this.dataStoreExample.next(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Service B depends on Service A, and emits a value only when Service A finishes its job. home.ts in turn will receive the value only when it is emitted by B (again, after A finishes its job).

home.ts:

```
export class home {
  constructor(
    public Events: Events,
    public BService: BService
  ) {
      this.BService.dataFromServiceB.subscribe(
        (data) => console.log('BService Ready from home, got data:', data),
        (error) => console.log('BService FAIL from home, error:', error)
      );
  }
}
```

See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-yvza2i?file=pages/home/home.ts